# jQuery Form Plugin’s File Upload issue when string returned from server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-forms-plugin

I am trying to use `jQuery Form` Plugin to upload files. It is uploading to a ASP.NET MVC controller action with a return type `string`.

**Controller Action with String return type**

```
 [HttpPost]
 public string PracticeInfoFormUpload(HttpPostedFileBase myfile, FormCollection formCollection)
 {
      //Store the file on disk (Logic excluded for brevity)
      return “good”;
 }
```

The file is uploaded and response is displayed in Chrome and Firefox. But when I use IE, it is showing the response string in a new page. How to fix this to work in IE also?

Note: The file is getting uploaded correctly in IE also. The problem is what it does with the response unlike other browsers.

Note: I am using **IE-10**

**Expected Result and IE Issue**

[image]

[image]

**jQuery**

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var bar = $('.bar');
            var percent = $('.percent');
            var status = $('#status');

            $('#frmUpload').ajaxForm({
                beforeSend: function () {
                    status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                success: function () {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    bar.width(percentVal)
                    percent.html(percentVal);
                },
                complete: function (xhr) {
                    var returnMessage = xhr.responseText;
                    //alert(xhr.responseText);
                    //status.html(xhr.responseText);
                    if (returnMessage == "good") {
                        status.html('<div style="Color:#00A000;"><i>File successfully uploaded</i></div>');
                    }
                    else {
                        status.html('<div style="Color:#FF0000;"><i>Error! Please try again</i></div>');
                    }

                }
            });

        });


    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
  <div style="float:left;width:100%;border:0px solid green;margin: 0 0 0 0px;">

                        @using (Html.BeginForm("PracticeInfoFormUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "frmUpload", id = "frmUpload" }))
                        {
                            <input type="hidden" name="Practice" value="DefaultText"><br>


                            <div class="input-group" style="margin-left:20px;">
                                <input type="file" class="form-control input-sm" name="myfile" id="myfile">
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload " style="margin:2px 0 2px 120px;" class="approvalRadioBackground">

                        }

                        <div style="width:80%; padding-left:50px; text-align:center; margin:3px 0 5px 0;">
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="bar"></div>
                                <div class="percent">0%</div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="status"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HTML code sample](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#html) documentation the ***target*** identifies the HTML element to update with the server response.

Try adding the line **target: '#status',** to the JS (as seen below)

```js
$('#frmUpload').ajaxForm({
        // target identifies the element(s) to update with response 
        target: '#status', 
        beforeSend: function () {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal)
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        //rest omitted for brevity...
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Tried this. No change

Answer (score 1):

1.You should use `ContentResult` in controller.

2.You should specify `contentType`,`dataType` in Ajax method in jquery

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ContentResult PracticeInfoFormUpload(HttpPostedFileBase myfile, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
      //Store the file on disk (Logic excluded for brevity)
       return Content("good");
    }
```

**Jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/PracticeInfoFormUpload",
    data: '{myfile: "' + yourdata + '" }',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: For the `ajaxForm`, I set contentType and dataType. And changed to ContentResult in controller.  Still the same issue.

Comment: @Lijo,Please Upload your jquery and controller code

Comment: Have you tried adding the target: '#status' line in the JS as shown in my edited answer?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things you can try:

1. You haven't set the id to `input`, assign id to it and access though this id `id="UploadId"`:

   ```
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="UploadId" 
      style="margin:2px 0 2px 120px;" class="approvalRadioBackground">
   ```
2. Or if not, then try this code:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() { 
       var options = {...
       /*abridged for clarity*/

       $('#upload').submit(function() {
           $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
           return false;
       });
   });
   ```
3. Internet Explorer will not allow you to submit a form for security reasons. Open your file browser through manually triggered `OnClick` instead of a submit it, actual clicking the button. After doing this the form plugin will work fine.

Comment: My code is working fine for IE11 and other browsers. Are you saying this change is needed specific to IE10?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your controller to return Json instead of a string.
You can try something like this :-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PracticeInfoFormUpload(HttpPostedFileBase myfile,FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        //Store the file on disk (Logic excluded for brevity)
        return new Json("good");
    }
```

Then change your code in your ajax request to contentType: "application/json"
dataType: "json"

Comment: Did you reproduce my issue in IE10? Did this approach solved the issue?